# cherrypy catch all route

Tags: python, cherrypy

Using Cherrypy how do I make this script so that any url will load the load index.html

example if any of these are used then they all load the index.html page
www.mtsite.test/111111/22222/333333
www.mtsite.test/1
www.mtsite.test/fred
www.mtsite.test/test

```
import os, os.path
import random
import string

import cherrypy

class StringGenerator(object):
   @cherrypy.expose
   " def *(self)
   def index(self):
       return file('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    conf = {
        '/': {
            'tools.sessions.on': True,
            'tools.staticdir.root': os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())
        },
        '/static': {
            'tools.staticdir.on': True,
            'tools.staticdir.dir': './public'
        }
    }


    webapp = StringGenerator()
    cherrypy.quickstart(webapp, '/', conf)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import cherrypy


config = {
  'global' : {
    'server.socket_host' : '127.0.0.1',
    'server.socket_port' : 8080,
    'server.thread_pool' : 4
  }
}


class App:

  @cherrypy.expose
  def default(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return u'It is me again at {0} with {1}'.format(args, kwargs)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  cherrypy.quickstart(App(), '/', config)
```